# Why doesn't OFS work?

Tags: awk

```
$ echo "a b c" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","}; {print $0};' -
a b c
```

I was trying to see if `OFS` applies after the last field, so expecting  the output to be either

```
a,b,c
```

or

```
a,b,c,
```

but the change of `OFS` doesn't work. Why is it?

Comment: Thanks. What constructs do you mean that I don't understand in this post? I have the book in pdf file, and on what page can I find them? I am reading The AWK Programming Language by Aho et al, right now.

Comment: ok. But what constructs do you mean that I don't understand here?

Comment: OFS, print, field assignment, $0, awk syntax (those semi-colons are neither necessary nor desirable - just cluttering up your code), and how to call awk (you do not need to list `-` as a file name when reading from a pipe).

Comment: I would say that this is a good question. Even you read the book backward, this trap will still get you. Awk should provide a different way to print the output with the new value of OFS. Is there an alternative to $0? I know if you do { print $1, $2, $3 } the OFS will be used even you did not update any fields.  However, this requires you know the exact number of columns in the data and it is not portable to a different input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should change/set a field, so that the `$0` is recomputed, then `OFS` will be applied. E.g.

```
echo "a b c" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","}; {$1=$1;print $0};'
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Why does it work that way? (2) Is it similar for other builtin variables, such as ORS, ....? or is it unique for OFS?

Comment: only assigning value to a field causing $0 to be recomputed. `sub(), gsub()` on `$0` won't.  If there is no change on fields, when you print $0, awk take the whole line, not NF fields. same for sub/gsub  I think one reason of this is performance.@Tim

Comment: @Tim (2) No, ORS will be applied in all cases. because it looks row, not fields. When you print a row  the ORS comes with anyway.

Comment: Because sometimes we want to print whatever is in the input without touching it.  If we write to a field, **awk** is forced to do the line buffer conversion of FS to OFS. Idiomatic **awk** for this is: echo "a b c" | awk -v OFS=, '$1=$1'

Comment: @MichaelBack no, the idiomatic awk would be `echo "a b c" | awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1'` so the line is printed even if it's first field is the null string or evaluates to zero.  Try both approaches if the first field is `0` instead of `a`.

Comment: Yup Ed -- mine's buggy.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks. I can't find in  Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition by Arnold Robbins, or The AWK Programming Language by Aho,  the thing you mentioned in your post. Do you know if the books mention it?

Comment: @Tim I don't have the book and I haven't read the book either.. sorry

Comment: @Tim by testing and reading man page (man gawk, then `/OFS Enter`) also the awk is open source project.

Answer (score 4):

{ print $1, $2, $3 } will use the OFS value regardless of any fields got updated or not. But this solution is not portable.  I am hoping other better solutions such as print $WITH_OFS that may be a new feature of AWK.

Answer (score 2):

$0 is not modified by assigning to OFS.  $0, however, gets modified when you assign to any of its elements, including any non-existing fields.

> echo "a b c" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","}; {$4="";print $0};' -

gives: a,b,c,